# Need help formulating getCategoryIds() statement

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I am having trouble working with getCategoryIds() and would greatly appreciate help formulating this statement

```
$one = 71;
$two = 8;
$three = 4;

$categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();

if(($one || $two || $three) is in $categoryIds)
{
do stuff;
}
```

I'm unsure of how to pull out all the categoryIds that a product might have (i.e. 5,7,2) and match against the hardcoded ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use array_intersect (http://php.net/array_intersect), this returns you an array with values that exist in both given arrays, so you just have to count (or check if it's empty) the returned array:

```
$myIds = array(71, 8, 4);

$categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();

$result = array_intersect($myIds, $categoryIds);

if (count($result)) {
    // do stuff;
}
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much for the help! I actually learned a lot from that explanation and am looking forward to being able to apply that method again in the future!